# Update Squid on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS

Tags: server, 22.04, proxy, lts, squid

I installed squid (v. 5.2) on a fresh Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS, but we see a lot of aborted downloads together with error messages in in squids log files.

The info from squid mailing list was:

"... Squid v5.2 has a set of bugs that make it unusable in most production environments ..."

and they suggest to update to 5.6 or later.

Any suggestions how to get out of this dilemma? Is there a smooth way to update to 5.6 without breaking much?

Thanks in Advance.

Thomas

Comment: you shouldn't have marked that answer as the accepted one. You should have waited longer, for other users to submit more proposals via apt or .deb, since everything indicates that the only stable version is 5.7. Before that they are full of bugs (ubuntu was wrong to put 5.2 in its LTS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really any good way to do this using `apt` packages, because this will likely cause dependency problems. But this is why containers were invented. So the two best options are.

1. Snap
2. Docker

Unfortunately, there isn't any active maintainer for a Squid package in Snap, so Docker is the best bet.

I found this [Docker Squid image](https://hub.docker.com/r/b4tman/squid), which seems well maintained.

As always, do your own research when getting container images from the web.