# Usable squid version for Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: server, proxy, lts, squid

I use Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS with latest patch level.
The server ist used as a squid - proxy server.
Squid version is 5.2-1ubuntu4.3
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/squid/5.2-1ubuntu4.3
Even with this latest update squid is unfortunately not useable because it keeps crashing with these messages:

```
FATAL: check failed: opening()#012    exception location: tunnel.cc(1299) noteDestinationsEnd#012
```

The fatal error occurs every 15 to 30 Minutes. The squid process reloads but for example teams sessions which use the squid proxy break down.

The problem seems to be similar to the one described in this post:
[Update Squid on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419236/update-squid-on-ubuntu-server-22-04-lts)
It is not possible to use squid in a docker container in my environment as implied in the post.

Are there other proposals to solve the problem?
Are there plans to update and include the 5.7 squid version in Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS?

All best
Hans

Comment: Please check the bug tracker to see if you issue has been reported, and the status of a fix. LTS releases generally get patches, not new versions without a very good reason -- so far, nobody has offered a compelling reason to justify an exception.

Comment: @Terrance: Thanks for proof reading :)

Comment: @user535733: Thanks for the tip. I opened a case: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/squid/+bug/2009682